# Is "make me to go" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, predicate-frames, infinitive-constructions

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> You can’t make me **to** go with you.

Is the word *to* required there or not, and why?

Comment: Definitely no 'to'. To "make something go" is a compound verb. I am not sure why you would want to put a 'to' there.

Comment: The sentence is not grammatical. The word "to" is not a preposition. The word "cant" does not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When some verbs -- and "make" is one of them -- take an infinitive as an object or objective complement, the particle "to" is omitted.  This construct is called a "**bare infinitive**.  The correct sentence is

> You can't make me **go** with you.

Comment: Many years ago, a to-infinitive was quite normal. '...they made him to go down' [[Swedenborg_Works](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=hC89AAAAcAAJ&pg=PA15&lpg=PA15&dq=%22they+made+him+to+go%22+-%22they+made+him+to+be%22&source=bl&ots=GaSXGhEF6s&sig=ACfU3U2w-Eq8sURhclqfaDU_laqnDEORwQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwid6oj9-MvlAhV0o3EKHRyaA6MQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22they%20made%20him%20to%20go%22%20-%22they%20made%20him%20to%20be%22&f=false)]. But note that 'He was made to carry the box' requires the 'to'.

Answer (score 0):

The verb construction verb+object+bare infinitive is used

1 with verbs of cause or allowing: to make s do sth (s is someone, sth is something), to have s do sth, to bid s do sth, to let s do sth. The object may also be a thing.

2 after verbs of perception as to see, to watch etc.

It seems that these two patterns are so frequent that the infinitive particle to was dropped.